# Grey out and make text box read only using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi i want to make a text box turn grey and be made read only when a checkbox is ticked. Currently i am able to get the text box to be made read only but will not turn grey. I would usually use the disabled attribute, however i need the value of the text box still to be sent so the disabled attribute can not be used here as it returns a null value.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   $("#redflag2").click(function () {
      $('#new_contracted_support_hours').attr("readonly", $(this).is(":checked"));
      $('#new_contracted_support_hours').addclass("greyba", $(this).is(":checked"));
  });
});
```

css

```
.greyba{
    background-color:rgba(178,178,178,1.00);

}
```

Comment: can't you make text color as `rgba(178,178,178,1.00)` rather than bkgrdcolor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `addClass()` not `addclass()` thus class was not added.

You should use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set properties and `toggleClass()`,

> As of jQuery 1.6, the `.prop()` method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while `.attr()` retrieves attributes.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("#redflag2").change(function () {   
        $('#new_contracted_support_hours')
            .prop("readonly", this.checked)
            .toggleClass("greyba", this.checked);
    });
});
```

A good read [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   $("#redflag2").click(function () {
      $('#new_contracted_support_hours').attr("readonly", $(this).is(":checked"));
      if($(this).is(":checked")){
         $('#new_contracted_support_hours').addClass("greyba");
      }
   });
```

```js
$("#redflag2").click(function () {
$('#new_contracted_support_hours').attr("readonly", $(this).is(":checked"));
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $('#new_contracted_support_hours').addClass("greyba");
}
else{
    $('#new_contracted_support_hours').removeClass("greyba");
}
});
```

```css
.greyba{
    background-color:rgba(178,178,178,1.00);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="new_contracted_support_hours" type="text"></input>
<input id="redflag2" type="checkbox"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not **separate your concerns** more clearly, leaving JS for functionality and CSS for styling? As you are usilising the `readonly` attribute, zero styling intervention is required in your Javascript.

nb. Implementation is indicative only

```js
function setState(){
  document.getElementById('field').readOnly = document.getElementById('checkbox').checked;
}
$('#checkbox').on('change', setState); // set state on checkbox change
setState(); // set state on initial load
```

```css
#field[readonly] {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
<input id="field" type="text" value="value.." />
```

Comment: @Satpal - its indicative only, and the main reason being the revision (see updated)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="viewers" name=""/>
```

You can make `readonly` by this by using:

```
$('#viewers').attr('readonly', true);
$('#viewers').css('background-color' , '#DEDEDE');
```